# How to append html content into iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I tried the code below but it completely replaces the content inside the iframe:

```
@ViewChild('iframe') iframe: ElementRef;

let content = '<h1>TEST CONTENT</h1>';
let doc = this.iframe.nativeElement.contentDocument;
doc.open();
doc.write(content);
doc.close();
```

How do I append html content into the iframe without replacing?

Comment: you could try get contents of iframe as a string, then append `content` var to it and write that?

Comment: maybe something like `doc.body.innerHTML += content;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.iframe.nativeElement.contentWindow.frames.document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', contentToAppend);
```

this worked for me. I get the iframe element in Angular with `ElementRef` & `@ViewChild` then dig down to it's HTML body and append HTML content using `insertAdjacentHTML` method, in the position desired, available as `beforebegin`, `afterbegin`, `beforeend` and `afterend`.

Answer (score 1):

insertAdjacentHTML is working similar innerHTML but faster than  innerHTML.
   element.insertAdjacentHTML(position, text);

```
'beforebegin': Before the element itself.
'afterbegin': Just inside the element, before its first child.
'beforeend': Just inside the element, after its last child.
'afterend': After the element itself.
```

Details  : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

```
       @ViewChild('iframe') iframe: ElementRef;
       let doc = this.iframe.nativeElement.contentDocument;
       doc.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<h1>TEST CONTENT</h1>');
```

I hope it help you.

Answer (score 0):

*doc.open()* [removes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/open) all the document's contents

You should either add your text as text as suggested in comments or append it inside ex. `body`

```
doc.body.append(content)
```

Answer (score -3):

instead of this solution you can use jquery Selector to append your content:

```
$("#specific_iframe_id").append(content);
```

Comment: no where does the OP mention jQuery - not everyone wishes to use jQuery